# How to Trigger an event when new AMI is added to a region

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am working on AWS Instance creation Automation . I need to trigger event when new AMI is created in a region.

Appreciate your help

---

the tags are self explanatory . It's about AWS services. Whenever a new API is created I need to run a event/lambda . I somehow need to detect whenever new API is created .

Comment: Avoid one liner question. If you really need help, be as descriptive as possible. Do not assume everyone is familiar with what you do.

Comment: @helloV the tags are self explanatory . It's about AWS services. Whenever a new API is created I need to run a event/lambda . I somehow need to detect whenever new API is created .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke an event depending on the EC2 instance state or your Auto Scaling group. Check this out how to create an event for [CloudWatch Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/LogEC2InstanceState.html) and for [AS Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/LogASGroupState.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever a new API is created I need to run a event/lambda . I somehow
>   need to detect whenever new API is created .

I guess that you are speaking about AMI and not API.

There is no CloudWatch Event corresponding to the creation of an AMI.
So you can not have such a trigger in a simple way.
You need to poll the EC2 API waiting until the AMI is created.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CloudWatch Event when the Status changes to "pending" which is what happens what an Instance is created.  I have not figured out how to pass the Instance-ID of the new instance to the Lambda function, yet.

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ],
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "pending"
    ]
  }
}
```